# How to pass props into createTheme() in Material-ui theme object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have used the docs to create a theme object in `/theme.js` and I'm importing it in a wrapper component in `_app.tsx`. I can't figure out how to pass props (i.e. a 'darkMode' prop) that would be able to be accessed in the theme file. Here's how it's setup:

_app.tsx:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState)

  useEffect(() => {
    if ((global.window as any).Cypress) {
      global.window.store = store
      console.log("Cypress store is running and linked to global document")
    }
  },[])

  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Head>
        <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' name='viewport' />
      </Head>
      <ContextWrapper>
        <LayoutWrapper>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </LayoutWrapper>
      </ContextWrapper>
    </Provider>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

my ContextWrapper component:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core'
import theme from '../styles/theme'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import userActions from '../store/actions/userActions'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const ContextWrapper:React.FC = ({children: children}) => {
  const { loggedIn } = useSelector((state: any) => state.userState)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem('user_object')
    if (user) {
      dispatch({ type: userActions.LOG_IN, payload: JSON.parse(user) })
    } else if (router.pathname != '/signup-test') {
      router.push('/signup-test')
    }
  }, [loggedIn])


  return(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default ContextWrapper
```

my theme.js file:

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core'
// Info on themeing here -> https://next.material-ui.com/customization/theming/

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
    primary: {
      main: '#777777'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#333333'
    },
    medGray: {
      main: "#999999"
    },
    navBar: {
      main: '#ffffff'
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: "contained",
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderRadius: '2rem'
        }
      }
    },
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      defaultProps: {
        inputProps: {

        }
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          marginBottom: '1rem',
          borderRadius: '2rem',
          border: 'none',
          ":before": {
            border: 'none'
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
})

export default responsiveFontSizes(theme)
```

I'd like to pass a prop or value to my theme where I can control certain values.
For instance: `palette: { mode: darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light }`

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it. I had to go a level deeper than _app.tsx because I'm using NextJS ISR and needed data that is accessible at build time.

My useSettings hook is simply reading from localstorage, but you could use redux or whatever to get your settings.

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import buildTheme from '../../theme';
import useSettings from '../../hooks/useSettings';

interface DisplayProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}
export const Display: React.FC<DisplayProps> = ({ children }) => {
    let prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

    const { settings } = useSettings();

    const theme = React.useMemo(() => {
        if (settings.theme && settings.theme!=='system') {
            prefersDarkMode = settings.theme === 'dark';
        }
        return buildTheme(prefersDarkMode, {
            direction: settings.direction,
            responsiveFontSizes: settings.responsiveFontSizes,
            theme: settings.theme,
        });
    }, [prefersDarkMode, settings]);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default Display;
```

theme.ts

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core';

export const commonThemeSettings = {
    breakpoints: {
        keys: ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'],
        values: { xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 960, lg: 1280, xl: 1920 },
    },
    direction: 'ltr',
    mixins: {
        toolbar: {
            minHeight: 56,
            '@media (min-width:0px) and (orientation: landscape)': {
                minHeight: 48,
            },
            '@media (min-width:600px)': { minHeight: 64 },
        },
    },
    typography: {
        htmlFontSize: 16,
        fontFamily: '"SharpBook19", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeightLight: 400,
        fontWeightRegular: 400,
        fontWeightMedium: 400,
        fontWeightBold: 400,
        h1: {
            fontSize: '3rem',
        },
        h2: {
            fontSize: '2.5rem',
        },
        h3: {
            fontSize: '2.25rem',
        },
        h4: {
            fontSize: '2rem',
        },
        h5: {
            fontSize: '1.5rem',
        },
        shape: { borderRadius: 0 },
    },
    palette: {
        primary: {
            light: '#7986cb',
            main: '#3f51b5',
            dark: '#303f9f',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        secondary: {
            light: '#ff4081',
            main: '#f50057',
            dark: '#c51162',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        error: {
            light: '#e57373',
            main: '#f44336',
            dark: '#d32f2f',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        warning: {
            light: '#ffb74d',
            main: '#ff9800',
            dark: '#f57c00',
            contrastText: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
        },
        info: {
            light: '#64b5f6',
            main: '#2196f3',
            dark: '#1976d2',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        success: {
            light: '#81c784',
            main: '#4caf50',
            dark: '#388e3c',
            contrastText: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
        },
        grey: {
            50: '#fafafa',
            100: '#f5f5f5',
            200: '#eeeeee',
            300: '#e0e0e0',
            400: '#bdbdbd',
            500: '#9e9e9e',
            600: '#757575',
            700: '#616161',
            800: '#424242',
            900: '#212121',
            A100: '#d5d5d5',
            A200: '#aaaaaa',
            A400: '#303030',
            A700: '#616161',
        },
        contrastThreshold: 3,
        tonalOffset: 0.2,
        action: {
            disabledOpacity: 0.38,
            focusOpacity: 0.12,
        },
    },
};
export const lightPalette = {
    type: 'light',
    text: {
        primary: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
        secondary: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)',
        disabled: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)',
        hint: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)',
    },
    divider: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
    background: { paper: '#fff', default: '#fafafa' },
    action: {
        active: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)',
        hover: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)',
        hoverOpacity: 0.04,
        selected: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)',
        selectedOpacity: 0.08,
        disabled: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)',
        disabledBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
        focus: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
        activatedOpacity: 0.12,
    },
};
export const darkPalette = {
    type: 'dark',
    text: {
        primary: '#fff',
        secondary: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
        disabled: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        hint: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        icon: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    },
    divider: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)',
    background: { paper: '#424242', default: '#303030' },
    action: {
        active: '#fff',
        hover: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08)',
        hoverOpacity: 0.08,
        selected: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16)',
        selectedOpacity: 0.16,
        disabled: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
        disabledBackground: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)',
        focus: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12)',
        activatedOpacity: 0.24,
    },
};

const theme = (preferDark, additionalOptions) => {
    let theme = createTheme({
        ...commonThemeSettings,
        palette: preferDark
            ? { ...darkPalette, ...commonThemeSettings.palette }
            : { ...lightPalette, ...commonThemeSettings.palette },
        ...additionalOptions,
    });
    if (additionalOptions && additionalOptions.responsiveFontSizes) {
        theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
    }
    return theme;
};

export default theme;
```